# Hiding text on hover of menu and submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide a text when I hover in my menu1 and on its sub menus too.
How can I do it ?
Here is my code :
 http://jsfiddle.net/bulina/F2R7F/

```
<p id="text"> <b>This is the text that will hide on hover</b> </p>
<div id="menu4">
<ul>
<li id="list"><center><a href="#" >Menu1</a></center>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Sub1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub5</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub6</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub7</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub8</a></li>
</ul>
</li>   

<li><center><a href="#">Menu2</a></center>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Sub1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub2</a></li>

</ul>
</li>

<li><center><a href="#">Menu3</a></center>
<ul>

<li><a href="#">Sub7</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub8</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</div>
```

Comment: Your fiddle works fine, just a syntax error & you forgot to include jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/dg25x/

Comment: But it doesn't work for my submenus ?

Comment: @Bulina Use mouseover instead of hover or use hover like this `hover(function(){},function(){});` http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/F2R7F/2/

Answer (score 0):

We can use [jQuery hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) method to handle both mouseEnter and mouseLeave events
by using its callbacks respectively.

```
$(selector).hover(mouseIn, mouseOut)
```

In above question, two different jQuery methods of `hover` and `mouseout`  plays an independent role on same #text element. Hence their working doesn't give expected output.

All credits to @anton.
Refer fiddle from @anton comment above :  [jsfiddle.net/Alfie/F2R7F/2](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/F2R7F/2/)

Comment: Is pretty good, Provide some explanation about Why you code would help her.

Comment: @WilfredoP , I hope this would help